# jQuery Mobile: toggle some property on a Collapsible so it is either openable or not

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to prevent a user from seeing the more advanced content in a 2nd/3rd jQuery Mobile Collapsible until they pass a quiz and prep in the end of the 1st Collapsible. My thought is to give them a tooltip on the 2nd/3rd Collapsible telling them to take the quiz and prep if they try to open it skipping the end of the 1st Collapsible.  How would I:

1) prevent the 2nd/3rd Collapsible from opening, and after passing

2) allow them to open the 2nd Collapsible and remove the tool tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if You need an `"beforeexpand"` event, you can override the internal `_handleExpandCollapse` function:

```js
var passedFirst = false;

$.widget("mobile.collapsible", $.mobile.collapsible, {
  _handleExpandCollapse: function(isCollapse) {
    var opts = this._renderedOptions, ui = this._ui;
    var retval = this._trigger(isCollapse ? "beforecollapse" : "beforeexpand" );
    if(!retval) return false;
    ui.status.text(isCollapse ? opts.expandCueText : opts.collapseCueText);
    ui.heading.toggleClass("ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed", isCollapse).find("a").first()
      .toggleClass("ui-icon-" + opts.expandedIcon, !isCollapse)
      .toggleClass("ui-icon-" + opts.collapsedIcon, (isCollapse || opts.expandedIcon === opts.collapsedIcon))
      .removeClass($.mobile.activeBtnClass);
    this.element.toggleClass("ui-collapsible-collapsed", isCollapse);
    ui.content.toggleClass("ui-collapsible-content-collapsed", isCollapse)
      .attr("aria-hidden", isCollapse).trigger("updatelayout");
    this.options.collapsed = isCollapse;
    this._trigger(isCollapse ? "collapse" : "expand");
  }
});

$(document).on("collapsibleexpand", "#pass1", function(event, ui) {
  passedFirst = true;
}); 

$(document).on("collapsiblebeforeexpand", "#pass2", function(event, ui) {
  var t = event.currentTarget, x = t.offsetLeft, y = t.offsetTop + t.scrollTop;
  if(!passedFirst) $("#extra-info" ).popup("open", {x: x, y: y});
  return passedFirst;
}); 

$(document).on("popupafteropen", "#extra-info", function(event, ui) {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function(){$(self).popup("close"); }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Collapsible beforeexpand</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div data-role="collapsible" id="pass1">
        <h3>Pass 1</h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
      </div>
      <div data-role="collapsible" id="pass2">
        <h3>Pass 2</h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="extra-info" data-role="popup" data-transition="flip">
      <p>You must pass #1!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

About the `Popup`: here is the full documentation: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks Deblocker!!!  I hope you see this used on a website that "blesses the hell out of you".  If you do see that website, know you helped make that possible for all.  Thank you for such beautiful work.

Comment: It also strikes me that this library and/or jQuery UI with it's accordion might have an option to "force" the open of its contents in order, probably useful for various applications requiring order. Sometimes "less complexity for user is more" (often).   Do you know know those guys?  If not I'll try to submit ...